# Tile objects on the area

Tags: c#, algorithm, autocad

I have AutoСad drawing, which has painted polygons and area(canvas). My goal is to place polygons on the area in a particular order, its must do not overlap. 
The only way that comes to my mind is to make a matrixes (two-dimensional arrays) of the canvas and each polygon and then place the polygons in the area by checking the values ​​in two-dimensional arrays.

The problem is that the area is quite large, it is painting 2500x1250 and circulation process of the two-dimensional array of this size is very demanding to PC resources. Perhaps there are some other ways?